# Use \blacktriangleright as itemize label

Tags: itemize, enumitem

I'm using `enumitem` package and I want to create an itemize list with the `\blacktriangleright` symbol in front of each line.

However, writing

```
\begin{itemize}[label=$\blacktriangleright$]
    \item $P(T \cap D) = P(T|D)P(D)$
    \item $P(T \cap \overline{D}) = P(T|\overline{D})P(\overline{D}) = (1 - P(\overline{T}|\overline{D}))(1 - P(D))$
    \item $P(\overline{T} \cap D) = P(\overline{T}|D)P(D) = (1 - P(T|D))P(D)$
    \item $P(\overline{T} \cap \overline{D}) = P(\overline{T}|\overline{D})P(\overline{D})$
```

returns an error "! Undefined control sequence \labelitemi ->\blacktriangleright".

Is there any easy way to do this ?

Comment: What kind of an error? It can say a lot about what the problem is.

Comment: `\blacktriangleright` is a math symbol and needs math mode. You need to put it between dollar signs `\begin{itemize}[label=$\blacktriangleright$]` (and of course you need the package `amssymb`).

Comment: Did you load the `enumitem` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreeing with the user @Bernard with the use of the `enumitem` package I attach the complete MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label=$\blacktriangleright$]
    \item $P(T \cap D) = P(T|D)P(D)$
    \item $P(T \cap \overline{D}) = P(T|\overline{D})P(\overline{D}) = (1 - P(\overline{T}|\overline{D}))(1 - P(D))$
    \item $P(\overline{T} \cap D) = P(\overline{T}|D)P(D) = (1 - P(T|D))P(D)$
    \item $P(\overline{T} \cap \overline{D}) = P(\overline{T}|\overline{D})P(\overline{D})$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I will use `\mid` instead of `|` to have symmetrical blank spaces.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label=$\blacktriangleright$]
    \item $P(T \cap D) = P(T\mid D)P(D)$
    \item $P(T \cap \overline{D}) = P(T|\overline{D})P(\overline{D}) = (1 - P(\overline{T}\mid\overline{D}))(1 - P(D))$
    \item $P(\overline{T} \cap D) = P(\overline{T}\mid D)P(D) = (1 - P(T\mid D))P(D)$
    \item $P(\overline{T} \cap \overline{D}) = P(\overline{T}\mid \overline{D})P(\overline{D})$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like Campa said, I forgot to use package `amssymb`.
It works now.